# How or why did "sock" come to mean "punch"?

Tags: etymology, puns

I see that *sock* as an article of clothing is derived from Latin *soccus* for slipper. But, how did it also become a synonym for "a punch" or "to punch"?

Comment: I was hoping someone might find it linked to *Punch and Judy* somehow...

Comment: In Brazilian portuguese we say "soco" for a punch, and some say this comes from tupi-guarani, a mix of two Brazilian indigenous languages that were compiled by the first Portuguese missionaries.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It might be of *Wolof* origin. Here is an excerpt from [*The African Substratum in American English*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=1YkdAQAAIAAJ&q=sock%20%22to%20beat%20with%20a%20pestle%22&dq=sock%20%22to%20beat%20with%20a%20pestle%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_x928x7vJAhXBqx4KHQo4BfsQ6AEIRTAG) (by Margaret Wade-Lewis - 1988):

> **sock.** The colloquial verb to sock means 'to hit or strike forcefully,' 'to punch,' 'to deliver a blow' (American Heritage. 1976: 1226). **Its probable origin is the Wolof verb /s 1 k/ , meaning 'to beat with a pestle,' 'to strike' especially with something.**

<sub>Note: *[Wolof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolof_language)* (/ˈwɒlɒf/) is a language of Senegal, the Gambia, and Mauritania, and the native language of the Wolof people.</sub>

Moreover, the similar sounding verbs in English and Wolof are observed by the British linguist David Dalby in 1969 (from *[The Slavery Reader, Volume 1](https://books.google.ca/books?id=LVmqmz8L6NYC&pg=PA244&dq=sock%20%22to%20beat%20with%20a%20pestle%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidqZeIx7vJAhVIpx4KHX67ANoQ6AEIKTAB#v=onepage&q=sock%20%22to%20beat%20with%20a%20pestle%22&f=false)*
By Gad J. Heuman, James Walvin):

> The verb "sock," in the sense of "to strike," especially with something, has recently been popularized in the black American phrase "sock it to me" (with an obscene connotation), and is reminiscent of a similar-sounding verb in Wolof meaning "to beat with a pestle.

The *[Dictionary of Word Origins](https://books.google.ca/books/about/Dictionary_of_word_origins.html?id=mt6ArRqtDecC&redir_esc=y)* (by Joseph Twadell Shipley - 1945) has a different approach:

> Sock, in the slang sense, to beat, is one of a series. When you urge a dog to ***sick 'im***, the verb imitates the sound you make; a form of ***Seek him!*** (common Teut., AS. *secan*). One step stronger is to ***sock 'im*** ; the next stage, to ***soak 'im one***!

Then, the same book includes the etymology of sick, soak, steep, sugar and stoop; and tries to make a connection:

> If you are sick, the word is common Teut., AS. seoc.
> (Sickle is a diminutive, from L. secnla, from sccarc, to cut.) To soak, to steep, is fcom OE. socian, to suck in, a weak form of OE. sucan, whence Eng. suckj L. sh- gcrc, suet — , to suck; whence Eng. suction. A little one that sucks is a suckling; from this by backformation comes the verb, suckle. Sugar may have been influenced by L. sugere; it is win OFr. Sucre, from zuchrc, from LL. cuccarum, from Arab, sukkar. The verb to steep is from OE. steap, from OTeut. staupom, a vessel for water. The adjective steep is also from OE. steap, from OTeut. staup, stup; from this comes the OE. weak verb stupian, to lower, to bow, whence Eng. stoop. **One will stoop to put on (or dodge) a sock.**

<sub>Note: There might be typos in the excerpt. I copied and pasted the original text.</sub>

---

*OED*, *World wide words*, *The Routledge Dictionary of Historical Slang*, *Oxford Dictionary of Modern Slang* and some other similar sources; all say unknown origin. However, *OED* has the earliest citation from 1699:

> *Sock*, to Beat... *I'll Sock ye*, I'll Drub ye tightly.
>
> <sub>*B. E. · A new dictionary of the terms ancient and modern of the canting crew · 1st edition, 1699 (1 vol.)*</sub>

Comment: I found this a surprising yet credible explanation. Thanks for finding this.

Comment: Note that Margaret Wade-Lewis's citation of _The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language_ relates only to the definition of the verb _sock_. My 1969 and 1981 copies of _AHDEL_ have only this to say about the etymology of the verb: "[Origin obscure.]" And the fourth edition of  _AHDEL_ (2000) says "[Origin unknown.]" _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003) likewise has "[origin unknown]." So Wade-Lewis's assertion that "Its probable origin is the Wolof verb /s 1 k/..." expresses a level of confidence in the theory not shared by two prominent U.S. dictionaries.

Comment: @SvenYargs: Nevertheless, the influence of Wolof in American English is a very interesting subject of study, and not something that I had ever heard. This answer gave me a line to do some further research, which is why I wish to bestow a bounty.

Comment: @jxh: A perfectly reasonable decision on your part. Ermanen did a nice job (as usual) gathering different perspectives that went beyond the usual "origin unknown" boilerplate for words of dubious or contested provenance. I only wanted to caution about the uncertainty of Margaret Wade-Lewis's "Its probable origin is ..." pronouncement.

Comment: My last attempt succeeded in finding this snippet https://books.google.it/books?id=U9rh5emSEccC&q=%22One+will+stoop+to+put+on+(or+dodge)+a+sock%22&dq=%22One+will+stoop+to+put+on+(or+dodge)+a+sock%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgp4iOzePNAhWD5BoKHTErDLUQ6AEIHDAA

Comment: Because the excerpt in the link you posted is not visible to me, I searched a bit online and found two snippets: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=U9rh5emSEccC&q=weak+verb+stupian,&dq=weak+verb+stupian,&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOk9LxzuPNAhWBVRoKHbDKB8MQ6AEIHDAA

Answer (score 6):

The origin is unclear according to Etymonline:

***[Sock](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=sock&searchmode=none):***

> - sock (v.1) 1700, "to beat, hit hard, pitch into," ***of uncertain origin.*** To sock it to (someone) first recorded 1877.
> - sock (n.2) 
>     "a blow, a hit with the fist," 1700, from or related to sock (v.1)

Sock:

> - A blow; a beating. Chiefly in phr. ***to give (one) sock(s,***  to give a sound thrashing or beating. Also in phr. ***a sock in the eye (also fig.)***
>
>   - ***a 1700*** B. E. Dict. Cant. Crew s.v. Tip, Tip the Culls a Sock, for they are sawcy, Knock down the Men for resisting.
>   - ***1864 Slang Dict.***  240 ‘Give him Sock,’ i.e. thrash him well. -

Comment: Interesting. [This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sock+it%2C+he+got+socked%2C+he+socked%2C+sock+me&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Csock%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsock%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSock%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSock%20It%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSOCK%20IT%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Che%20socked%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhe%20socked%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHe%20socked%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Csock%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsock%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSock%20me%3B%2Cc0) suggests popularity beginning 1860-1920 or so, which jives.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. The (n.1) definition has an interesting reference to *knock the socks off*. Perhaps it is related to that?

Comment: @jxh - actually that expression was used later "*knock the socks off (someone) "beat thoroughly" is recorded from 1845*".

Comment: @Nonnal: _jibes_

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: Ack, that's embarrassing. Thanks for the correction. This will heretofore be known as my Grammar Achilles Heel. Achilles' Heel. Achilles's he'll. Or something.

Comment: @Nonnal: Think of it as Achilles' Heal, if you'll forgive the pun.

Comment: Utter speculation: could be related to putting anything heavy into a sock (the footwear) and using that as a weapon, as seen in *Full Metal Jacket*. This would of course require that such footwear be called a "sock" as opposed to "hose" or "hosen" prior to the introduction of this sense.

Answer (score 5):

In the reference works that I consulted, the briefest answer offered to this question was also the most disappointing. From John Ayto, [*Arcade Dictionary of Word Origins*](https://books.google.com/books?id=hsRISNLSSHAC&pg=PT843&dq=%22the+origins+of+sock+hit%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjE-avdr7vJAhVY32MKHSqgBlEQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22the%20origins%20of%20sock%20hit%22&f=false) (1990):

> The origins of *sock* 'hit' {17[th century]} are not known.

Ernest Weekley, [*An Etymological Dictionary of Modern English*](https://books.google.com/books?id=VigsBojU2c4C&pg=PT170&dq=%22to+beat+to+give+socks%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj77dXKr7vJAhVP1mMKHdbJDlIQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22to%20beat%20to%20give%20socks%22&f=false), volume 2 (1921) has this:

> **sock<sup>2</sup>**. To beat, to give *socks*. Cant, of unknown origin.
>
> > *sock*: a pocket, also to beat. *I'll sock ye*: I'll drub ye tightly (*Dict. Cant. Crew*).

The reference in Weekley is to [*A New Canting Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=A6NWAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT109&dq=%22sock+a+pocket%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_j9CTtrvJAhVW42MKHTkXBVIQ6AEISjAG#v=onepage&q=%22sock%20a%20pocket%22&f=false) (1725):

> SOCK, a Pocket. *Not a Rag in my Sock* ; I han't a Farthing in my Pocket. Also to beat ; *I'll sock ye* ; I'll drub ye tightly.

So we have a firm occurrence of *sock* in the relevant sense from 1725, in a glossary entry that also identifies a slang meaning of *sock* as a noun ("a Pocket"). The juxtaposition here does not imply an etymological connection between the verb *sock* and the noun *sock*, however.

It may be tempting to connect the violent verb *sock* with the longer phrase "knock the socks off [someone]." But according to Glynnis Chantrell, *The Oxford Dictionary of Word Histories* (2002), that phrase is later and from the United States:

> The phrase *knock the socks off* was originally US English from the early 19th century; ...

The only reference work I've found that actually hazards a guess as to the origin of *sock* as "hit or punch" is Eric Partridge, *Origins: A Short Etymological Dictionary of Modern English* (1966):

> **sock** (3), to throw or hit violently: sl[ang]: o[f] o[bscure] o[rigin]: prob[ably] echoic.

A nice discussion of usage of *sock* in England circa 1900 appears in [*Notes and Queries*](https://books.google.com/books?id=m2QEAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA53&dq=%22sock+him%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjf9vW0r7vJAhVV72MKHVGKCFIQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22sock%20him%22&f=false) (January 20, 1900), but nothing offered there as a possible source of the meaning is persuasive.

"Origin unknown" is the most accurate etymological conclusion to draw from these sources, I think.

Comment: One might hazard a guess that the term comes from using a rock in one's purse (or other commonly-carried bag) as a weapon.  A 30cm long bag containing a 300 gram rock (for example) would be an effective weapon if slung around.

Comment: @HotLicks: That was in fact a suggestion offered by Thomas J. Jeakes in the above-cited issue of _Notes & Queries_: "A stone in the heel of a sock or stocking is a well-known extempore life preserver or taker." Also of note in that discussion: John T. Page, of West Haddon, Northamptonshire, says that in his locality _sock_ can mean "'to throw' e.g., 'I'll sock a stone at you'" or "'to beat or to clout,' e.g., 'I'll fetch you a sock o' the ear-hole.'"